# Sprite kit easing/pause issue

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, action, easing

I'm trying to implement a pause function to my game. So far I've got it to work by setting my sprites speed to "0". But the sprites on which I've applied easing behave strange when pause button (speed = 0) is pressed; Their translation - Both location and rotation jump to another time/place in the action both when speed is set to "0" as well as when they are reset to "1". I would very much appreciate some input on this issue - Either a fix for my code or a better way of doing it :)

My sprite's movement code:

```
SKAction* _movePlayerUp = [SKAction moveToY:200 duration:3];
movePlayerUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
[_playerSprite runAction: movePlayerUp];
```

Function to enable pause:

```
  _playerSprite.speed = 0;
```

Function to disable pause:

```
  _playerSprite.speed = 1;
```

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Espen

Comment: speed is not for pausing, use node.paused=YES

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping this newbie out! Works like a charm :) You guys are really helpful and clearly talented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LearnCocos2D is right (because when is Setffen Itterheim wrong?) in saying that the correct way to pause your `_playerSprite` object is by setting the `paused` property to `YES`. If you're looking to pause your entire scene though, the best way to do it is to set the `paused` property on the `SKView` that contains the running `SKScene`. The `speed` property on an `SKAction` is used to adjust the timing on actions, not really to start or stop them.

Comment: OP was setting the speed of the node (property of SKNode) not the action.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I don't pause SKView is that I have an animation when Pause is enabled and an countdown when Pause is disabled. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: That makes sense. What you can do then is have everything you want paused in a container node and pause that node (all SKNodes have a paused property.) Then run your animation over it